# Dispatch logout action from axios interceptor

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js, react-context, http-status-code-401

Please let me know how to wrap the Axios interceptor to catch the api response for token expiry i.e 401 and call a dispatch action for logout from context, I would like to know how to call hooks inside the Axios.

Came up with the following solution but feel this is not the right way to do it and I could see buggy behaviour.

Please let me know how to address this without the solution being anti pattern.

NOTE: I have to call 2 dispatch actions 1) logout will remove all the localstorage values and do router.push to home page 2) Reset cart will set the cart counter value to zero saved in the store.

Created WithAxios component

// WithAxios.js

```
import { useMemo } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useUser } from '../store/User'
import { useCart } from '../store/Cart'
import { RESET_CART } from 'store/Cart/actions'

const WithAxios = ({ children }) => {
  const { logout } = useUser();
  const { dispatch: dispatchCart } = useCart()

  useMemo(() => {
    axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
      //console.log('response', response)
      return response
    }, async (error) => {
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        //console.log('response', error)
        dispatchCart({
          type: RESET_CART,
        })
        logout()
      }
      return error;
    })
  }, [])

  return children
}
```

And wrapped the component after all the context providers in _app.js file, This is a Next js App

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useCookie } from 'next-cookie'
import '../styles/main.css'
import UserProvider from '../store/User'
import PageProvider from '../store/Page'
import GlobalUIProvider from '../store/GlobalUI'
import BookingProvider from '../store/Booking'
import ExtraProvider from '../store/Extras'
import CartProvider from '../store/Cart'
import CheckoutProvider from '../store/Checkout'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { storePathValues } from '../utilities/helperFunctions'
import Layout from 'layouts/Layout'
import WithAxios from '../components/WithAxios'

const App = ({ Component: Pages, pageProps, cookie }) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const currenCookie = useCookie(cookie)

  return (
    <>
      <PageProvider model={pageProps}>
        <GlobalUIProvider>
          <UserProvider>
            <CartProvider>
              <CheckoutProvider>
                <BookingProvider>
                  <ExtraProvider>
                   <WithAxios>
                    <Layout
                      Pages={Pages}
                      pageProps={pageProps}
                      cookie={agentCookie}
                    />
                   </WithAxios>
                  </ExtraProvider>
                </BookingProvider>
              </CheckoutProvider>
            </CartProvider>
          </UserProvider>
        </GlobalUIProvider>
      </PageProvider>
    </>
  )
}

// NOTE: The limitation of specifying a default layout is that you can't pass serverside props to the component

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  return {
    props: {
      cookie: context.req.headers.cookie || '',
    },
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: A simple way is setting a ```localstorage``` item like "isLoggedIn" and delete it on 401 and redirect back to login page. Note: you can remove a cookie which has been set by server too. Also you can dispatch using store directly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962628/is-it-possible-to-trigger-a-redux-action-from-outside-a-component

Comment: @cybercoder The implementation is done using context api and i have to call the two dispatch actions logout (Reset localstorage values and do router.push to home page) and reset cart to setback the counter to 0 which is saved in the store.

Comment: redirect it to a logout component which you dispatch cleaning there and redirect to login page after that.

Comment: @cybercoderCan you please share an over view on the behaviour by giving out an example in terms of code, So it would be helpful to understand.